# How to write image in grayscale format in Magick++

Tags: c++, image-processing, imagemagick, magick++

How to save a `Magick::Image` in a grayscale format? I'm using `ImageMagick` to decode images and write the result to `OpenCV` matrix. What I'm doing now is reading the color image and then converting it to grayscale by `OpenCV`:

```
Magick::Image image("test.png");
cv::Mat mat(image.rows(), image.columns(), CV_8UC3);
image.write(0, 0, image.columns(), image.rows(), "BGR", Magick::CharPixel, mat.data);
cv::cvtColor(mat, mat, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

I'd like to write image to the `cv::Mat` already in grayscale, without the intermidiate color image. This should be very simple, but wasn't able to find it out from the docs and would appreciate any help.

Also I'd like to know how to detect if an image contains an alpha channel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set an image to grayscale, simple call `Magick::Image.type( Magick::ImageType )` before writing the image blob to cv.

```cpp
Magick::Image image("test.png");
image.type( Magick::GrayscaleType );
image.write(0, 0, image.columns(), image.rows(), "BGR", Magick::CharPixel, mat.data);
```

For detecting if an image has transparent, simply check if `Magick::Image.matte()` returns true.

```cpp
Magick::Image image("test.png");
std::cout << "transparent = " << ( image.matte() ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
```

Comment: You're still writing to a 3-channel matrix in BGR format. My goal is to obtain a single-channel grayscale matrix. Is it possible?

Comment: You should use cv::Mat mat(image.rows(), image.columns(), CV_8UC1); and specify "R" instead of "BGR".

Comment: @dlemstra is correct. Just drop the "BG" after switching to GrayscaleType. You can go more elaborate by separating the image to CMYK, and only writing the "K" channel, but that's overkill.